# How to test NestJS controller declared with with @Headers() decorator

Tags: nestjs

I have the following controller

```
@Controller('foo')
export class Foo {
    constructor() {}

    @Get()
    bar(@Headers() headers: Headers): void {
        return;
    }

}
```

My question is, how could I call `Foo.bar` in the test to test the bar method with the Headers function.

Comment: e2e testing or unit testing?

Comment: @JuanRambal For unit-testing

Comment: @staRain why not call `foo.bar({ x: y })` since `headers` is just an object? I didn't get it and I didn't see any other way that doesn't rely on `Test.createTestingModule`.If you're using Jest, you could use [@golevelup/ts-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@golevelup/ts-jest)

Comment: @MicaelLevi if in `foo.bar` method there is something like `headers['host']` then `foo.bar({ x: y })` is going to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have to access `myVar` of the header object in your controller

```
@Controller('foo')
export class Foo {
    constructor() {}

    @Get()
    bar(@Headers() headers: Headers): void {
        return `${headers.myVar}`;
    }

}
```

, So your spec can access the header like an object with Jest.

```
it('should return "myVar"', () => {
  const ret = foo.bar({
    myVar: 'hello',
  });
  expect(ret).toBe('hello');
});
```